# How to join two dataframes with different MultiIndex values and have one dataframe repeat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames with different resolution MultiIndex values. The first data frame tracks `state`, `year`, and `hour` variables, while the second data frame only tracks `state` and `hour` variables. How can I join the two data frames such that the second data frame is repeated for each year? Here is a small reprex:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

YEARS = np.arange(2015, 2055, 5)
HOURS = np.arange(1, 8761, 1)

idx0 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['NY'], YEARS, HOURS], names=['state', 'year', 'hour'])
df0 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(70080, 1),
    columns=['TOTALLOAD'],
    index=idx0
)
#                  TOTALLOAD
# state year hour
# NY    2015 1      0.283680
#            2      0.475532
#            3      0.309519
#            4      0.360841
#            5      0.835909
# ...                    ...
#       2050 8756   0.152357
#            8757   0.431416
#            8758   0.694271
#            8759   0.766727
#            8760   0.365636
# [70080 rows x 1 columns]

idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['NY'], HOURS], names=['state', 'hour'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(8760, 2),
    columns=['WIND', 'SOLAR'],
    index=idx1
)
#                 WIND     SOLAR
# state hour
# NY    1     0.835902  0.488313
#       2     0.066278  0.137335
#       3     0.600126  0.526955
#       4     0.661116  0.464443
#       5     0.547492  0.840770
# ...              ...       ...
#       8756  0.786757  0.829725
#       8757  0.753301  0.985739
#       8758  0.856252  0.196507
#       8759  0.322048  0.650752
#       8760  0.798451  0.050394
# [8760 rows x 2 columns]


# Expected Dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(70080, 3),
    columns=['TOTALLOAD', 'WIND', 'SOLAR'],
    index=idx0
)
#                  TOTALLOAD      WIND     SOLAR
# state year hour
# NY    2015 1      0.108648  0.767488  0.391436
#            2      0.012284  0.616722  0.314657
#            3      0.954200  0.666713  0.112874
#            4      0.078314  0.170395  0.697167
#            5      0.893799  0.356095  0.706867
# ...                    ...       ...       ...
#       2050 8756   0.233540  0.183593  0.178483
#            8757   0.473917  0.662912  0.135068
#            8758   0.124253  0.784875  0.528687
#            8759   0.350463  0.107292  0.446881
#            8760   0.223953  0.689475  0.425816
#
# [70080 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use:

```
df0.join(df1)
```

Because the MultiIndexes have two common levels, the join will be performed on those two and broadcasted to the third one by duplicating the rows.

Example:

```
>>> df0.join(df1).head()
                 TOTALLOAD      WIND     SOLAR
state hour year                               
NY    1    2015   0.164803  0.406091  0.822639
           2020   0.805777  0.406091  0.822639
           2025   0.480883  0.406091  0.822639
           2030   0.284095  0.406091  0.822639
           2035   0.811343  0.406091  0.822639
```

Comment: Wow, very simple solution. I noticed this changes the order of the index columns, does order of the index typically matter at all?

Comment: @dylanjm it depends on your usecase. If you care, it matters. If you don't mind, it matters not in the slightest.